# Get the location of httpd.exe in CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, apache-http-server, ms-dos

When we start the Apache in windows machine `httpd.exe` start its process.
Now we can determine if `httpd.exe` process is running or not using this command:

```
query process httpd.exe
```

This will return something like this:

```
 USERNAME        SESSIONNAME      ID    PID    IMAGE
 >system         services         0    3340   httpd.exe
 >system         services         0    4720   httpd.exe
```

Now, is it possible to get the location of the `httpd.exe` by using windows command in the cmd?
The command should return this *(location of `httpd.exe`)*:

```
E:\Installed Softwares\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\httpd.exe
```

Comment: We can get the running process list using TASKLIST command. For finding the location of the process, we can use process explorer.

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I get you, but if you want to locate file in **CMD** you can use **[where](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html)** comand *(it searches only in current directory and in path )* But you can put some parameters.
For example If I search for java.exe

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>where java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\java.exe
```

edit: You should try to search recursive and it will give you location, but it have worked for me only if file was on same partiton.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>where /r c:\ thunderbird.exe
c:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to get the location of the software that is  already running and can be view from the task manager as well.

Comment: Nope, "where" is not working

Comment: "where" is like the UNIX command "which". It looks for the file in the PATH, unless you specify the /R switch - which is much the same as doing *dir httpd.exe /S*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using WMI.
We need to construct a WQL query for processes which are called **httpd.exe**, and we want to get the path from which the executable was launched.
This information is kept in the [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, and the documentation shows us which bits of information we need to provide (eg *Name*), and which bits to ask for (eg *ExecutablePath*).

We can use [wmic.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290216) to query WMI like this:

```
wmic process WHERE name="httpd.exe" GET ExecutablePath
```

This should output something similar to:

```
C:\Apps\httpd.exe
C:\Apps\httpd.exe
C:\Apps\beta-test\httpd.exe
```

You might want to get the *CommandLine*, instead of the *ExecutablePath*, as this will also tell you which command line arguments the process has been launched with, and this can make a big difference when you're narrowing down which processes are doing what:

```
wmic process WHERE name="httpd.exe" GET CommandLine
```

This should show you something like:

```
C:\Apps\httpd.exe -config=E:\widgetsales\httpd.conf
C:\Apps\httpd.exe -config=E:\widgetservices\httpd.conf
C:\Apps\beta-test\httpd.exe -config=D:\DevStuff\httpd.conf
```

We can do even better, by getting the *PID* as well as the command line:

```
wmic process WHERE name="httpd.exe" GET CommandLine, ProcessID 

CommandLine                                                    ProcessId
C:\Apps\httpd.exe -config=E:\widgetsales\httpd.conf            51064
C:\Apps\httpd.exe -config=E:\widgetservices\httpd.conf         24716
C:\Apps\beta-test\httpd.exe -config=D:\DevStuff\httpd.conf     52728
```